# How to free up memory in a system that runs 24/7

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

So I have created this particular system which uploads data from local Disk to database, I just checked recently that it had consumed 667MB worth of memory (In a 1GB RAM computer) Is there anyway to somehow, clear the memory? I use `GC.Collect` and `Dispose` in every end of every sub.

Comment: keep less objects and dispose your unused objects properly

Comment: I always `dispose` every object that I finished using, followed by `GC.Collect`

Comment: This may be more suited to code review (I maybe wrong) however either way we need to see your code to understand what's going wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't call `GC.Collect()` manually. Dispose is enough.

Comment: Does it REALLY need to run 24/7. By the sound of it, this app would be better suited to run periodically under scheduler control.

Comment: @Trevor It really needs to run 24/7 because the data it is uploading is connected to a equipment, the equipment, or better yet, equipments (because there are 8 of them) creates the CSV files, sadly, we cannot schedule the equipment to, lets say , all of them should produce the data at 12 noon, its too complicated and complex that the best solution is a running background worker app.

Comment: @VisualVincent I thought forcing a Garbage Collection frees memory. I will follow your suggestion.

Comment: Then you have to go over your code with a fine tooth comb searching for things that are not disposed properly. If all else fails... you can fall back to the last resort self-reboot of the exe.

Comment: @Trevor Somehow this became the solution, self rebooting the app made sense.

Comment: It _might_ free up some memory, but the Garbage Collector is designed to run automatically and calling `GC.Collect()` isn't certain for it to act the same way as  when it finally runs on its own. As I said however `Dispose` is enough, the memory is usually freed right after.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your process doesn't have any memory leaks and check what is the max. memory usage in steady stage.Maybe it won't go farther.
Regulate size of data that you are loading and number of insert rows in bulk in case of rel. db or number of docs in case of non. rel. db.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot regulate the size of data to load, the data may contain from 8 hours up to 3 weeks worth of data. And the files range up from 2 CSV files per folder, up to 11 CSV files per loader.

Comment: Without proper load balancing you can do GC on whatever you want it still won't meter if you upload to much data into memory.
Start with bench-marking on maximum load.
Create queue with csv files(jobs) before you loading them.
You can read csv in bulks and insert them in the same way.